# Representing linear operator with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I've came across the following question in a book that I read about Hilbert spaces and linear operators - 
[image]

Where exercise $1$ is -

[image]

So the book has answers, and for 13a it is -

[image]

what I don't understand is how can we represent an operator which is defined by an infinite sequence, with a 2x2 matrix? how does it operate on other infinite sequences in $l_2$?

Comment: I suspect that what they have in mind is $w = (1,2,1,1,1,\dots)$.  We would be able to say that the "matrix" of this transformation is 
$$
D_w = \pmatrix{1\\&2\\&&1\\&&&\ddots}
$$

Comment: Please post critical parts of your question as text instead of pasting in pictures of it. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in question summaries. Use MathJax to format mathematical expressions; you can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).